# Duckiebot Flashing Micro SD Card Issue

Tags: ubuntu, sd-card, flashing

I am trying to flash my duckiebot using Ubuntu from the directions in their manual however when I go to choose where I want to flash it (the Micro SD Card) it will not show up and only gives me a list of places that are local to my computer such as the hard drive. Does anyone have an idea why the SD card won't show up even though it is recognized in the file explorer?[Picture of code with list of available devices to flash to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F96oY.png)

Everything is downloading but I just need to download it to the right device.